# MySQL query to pre-populate join table with all id combinations from two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which populates a join table with all 'theme' options for a given user.

```
INSERT INTO join_themes_users (join_theme_id, join_user_id);
SELECT theme_id, 1
FROM themes
```

What I now need to do is edit this query to populate the join table with all theme options for all users

Can this be done in a single query or will I need to create a for loop in PHP?

The above query produces results looking something like...

```
join_id     |     user_id      |      theme_id
----------------------------------------------------
1              1                  1
2              1                  2
3              1                  3
...
```

What I need is something like this...

```
join_id     |     user_id      |      theme_id
----------------------------------------------------
1              1                  1
2              1                  2
3              1                  3
...
14             2                  1
15             2                  2
16             2                  3
...
27             3                  1
28             3                  2
29             3                  3
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all combinations you cross join the tables:

```
INSERT INTO join_themes_users (join_theme_id, join_user_id)
SELECT themes.theme_id, users.user_id
FROM themes 
CROSS JOIN users
```

Comment: I'd not come across `CROSS JOIN` before but it did the trick! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. A cross join is something rarely needed. Its result is called a cartesian product. Maybe you've heard of that. People often involuntarily cross join when they use the outdated comma-separated join syntax (`FROM a, b`) and forget to add the join criteria.